# Is it good to perform scraping in server-side web framework(django)?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, django-views, frameworks, resources

let's consider, I need to provide clients(100+) a service through the website that scrape for a certain data from other sites. Is it good to perform the scraping things in server side or we can simply use client side (js)?
**Does it minimize the resource consumption of server?**

Expecting if i need to use django or just use js for this web development process?.

Comment: Hi, I think you should post some code. It's hard to tell what will be the results, without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use server-side as your clients may face numerous issues such as network, firewall, etc. Additionally, web scraping can be a time-consuming asynchronous task, so if you are already using the Django framework, I'll probably use Celery or Django-rq as queuing library to push long-running tasks in the queue and periodically check for status.